# Why the function does not take the new value assignment?

Tags: python, function

I've stumbled on a piece of code which looks like this:

```
x = 12
def f1(a,b=x):
    print(a,b)

x = 15
f1(4)
```

And in mind, I surely thought the answer is `4 15` since the call of the `f1` is after I assign  `x` to `15`, when I ran it I got `4 12`.

Why does it not print out `4 15` since `x` is `15` when I call `f1`?

**EDIT**

```
x = 12
def f1(a,b=x):
    print(x)
    print(b)
    print(a,b)

x = 15
f1(4)
```

Prints out

```
15
12
4 12
```

So the question becomes why `b` is not being updated with the new value of `x`?

Comment: Heh @Gabip, I was just updating my answer to include that link as well. Such link should help clarify the confusion indeed.

Comment: instead of expecting the default argument to change based on the state when the function is called, why not just pass in the new value: `f1(4, x)`. This is a far simpler pattern.

Comment: It's just a random code block I've found on Reddit, I wouldn't use this, just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `f1(b=x)`, the default of `b` now points to the same reference as `x` did. That is, both `x` and `b` refer to `12` now.

Changing what reference `x` points to later (`15`) does not affect what `b` points to (it's still `12`).

See also [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/986006/), and perhaps [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/) helps too.